# Mac: Get text under mouse cursor

Tags: macos

How to get the text under mouse cursor in macOS?

similar to [Lingoes Text Capture Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lingoes-text-capture-exte/pkijkcfcbkdfjfhddklifpmofknndggc?hl=zh-CN).

You don't need to install this extension, just see the preview images.

What I want to do is get the text under mouse cursor, might be another application or web content.

[image]

Comment: By text under mouse cursor, do you mean 'tooltip'? If so, do you want to display it programmatically or capture some existing text. Please provide some details.

Comment: @Aman please see [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lingoes-text-capture-exte/pkijkcfcbkdfjfhddklifpmofknndggc?hl=zh-CN), it's somehow similar to the Dictionary.app developed by Apple

Comment: If you want me or anyone on stack-overflow to install that extension, you are at wrong place. If you really want an answer to some problem, provide more details in your question.

Comment: @Aman my bad. You don't need to install this extension, just see the preview images.
When the cursor point to a word (in another application or web content), I want to get this word